# intermittent seg faults in text editor application

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5

A small qt application, which is a simple text editor. I just compile it under linux mint and when I run it I get segfault and sometimes I get `std::bad_alloc`,First I suspect crash reporter part

```
   virtual bool notify(QObject * receiver, QEvent * event) {
        //use https://github.com/AlekSi/breakpad-qt and publish first setup.
        //for setup http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php
        try
        {
            return QApplication::notify(receiver,event);
        }
        catch (const std::exception &exc)
        {
            // catch anything thrown within try block that derives from std::exception
            qDebug() << exc.what();
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            QMessageBox::warning(0,
                                 tr("An unexpected error occurred"),
                                 tr("This is likely a bug."));
            QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
            QString winVer=(QString)QSysInfo::prettyProductName();
            manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://mascix.com/bigfileeditor.jsp?winVer="+winVer)));
            qDebug()<<"http://mascix.com/bigfileeditor.jsp?winVer="+winVer;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I deleted it but the error still coming. [strace output](https://gist.github.com/ozkanpakdil/bdf4ed995e36b45392123634b1077b8d). below you can see how it throws the error
[image: segfault core dump]

below syslog

```
Mar 20 12:12:46 mint20 kernel: [40926.384026] big-file-editor[77160]: segfault at 21 ip 00007fb6ba862c0a sp 00007ffd716099b8 error 4 in libc-2.31.so[7fb6ba7d3000+178000]
Mar 20 12:12:46 mint20 kernel: [40926.384034] Code: f3 0f 1e fa 66 0f ef c0 66 0f ef c9 66 0f ef d2 66 0f ef db 48 89 f8 48 89 f9 48 81 e1 ff 0f 00 00 48 81 f9 cf 0f 00 00 77 66 <f3> 0f 6f 20 66 0f 74 e0 66 0f d7 d4 85 d2 74 04 0f bc c2 c3 48 83
Mar 20 12:12:46 mint20 systemd[1]: Started Process Core Dump (PID 77164/UID 0).
Mar 20 12:12:51 mint20 systemd-coredump[77165]: Process 77160 (big-file-editor) of user 1000 dumped core.#012#012Stack trace of thread 77160:#012#0  0x00007fb6ba862c0a __GI___strlen_sse2 (libc.so.6 + 0xb1c0a)#012#1  0x00007fb6bae2c06d _ZN16QCoreApplication9argumentsEv (libQt5Core.so.5 + 0x28a06d)#012#2  0x00007fb6b783512f n/a (libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 + 0x5012f)#012#3  0x00007fb6b7835602 _ZNK15QXcbIntegration7wmClassEv (libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 + 0x50602)#012#4  0x00007fb6b784baef _ZN10QXcbWindow6createEv (libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 + 0x66aef)#012#5  0x00007fb6b7836916 _ZNK15QXcbIntegration20createPlatformWindowEP7QWindow (libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 + 0x51916)#012#6  0x00007fb6bb3dbe15 _ZN14QWindowPrivate6createEby (libQt5Gui.so.5 + 0x12fe15)#012#7  0x00007fb6bba36808 _ZN14QWidgetPrivate6createEv (libQt5Widgets.so.5 + 0x19f808)#012#8  0x00007fb6bba36e0e _ZN7QWidget6createEybb (libQt5Widgets.so.5 + 0x19fe0e)#012#9  0x00007fb6bba43c4b _ZN14QWidgetPrivate10setVisibleEb (libQt5Widgets.so.5 + 0x1acc4b)#012#10 0x0000556c05f796ae n/a (/home/mlinux/tmp/big-file-editor/big-file-editor + 0x76ae)#012#11 0x0000556c06b1ecf0 n/a (n/a + 0x0)
Mar 20 12:12:51 mint20 systemd[1]: systemd-coredump@22-77164-0.service: Succeeded.
```

gdb backtrace output

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/mlinux/tmp/big-file-editor/big-file-editor 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff2d9a700 (LWP 78778)]
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
[New Thread 0x7ffff216f700 (LWP 78779)]
qt5ct: D-Bus global menu: no
[New Thread 0x7ffff115b700 (LWP 78781)]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc

Thread 1 "big-file-editor" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x00007ffff684c859 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff6ad7911 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff6ae338c in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff6ae33f7 in std::terminate() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff6ae36a9 in __cxa_throw () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff6c9fe7f in qBadAlloc() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#7  0x00007ffff6ca3d0e in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007ffff6d6ec9c in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007ffff6ea50de in QCoreApplication::arguments() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#10 0x00007ffff38ae12f in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#11 0x00007ffff38ae602 in QXcbIntegration::wmClass() const () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#12 0x00007ffff38c4aef in QXcbWindow::create() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#13 0x00007ffff38af916 in QXcbIntegration::createPlatformWindow(QWindow*) const () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#14 0x00007ffff7454e15 in QWindowPrivate::create(bool, unsigned long long) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#15 0x00007ffff7aaf808 in QWidgetPrivate::create() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#16 0x00007ffff7aafe0e in QWidget::create(unsigned long long, bool, bool) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#17 0x00007ffff7abcc4b in QWidgetPrivate::setVisible(bool) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#18 0x000055555555b6ae in main ()
```

here is the source code https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/big-file-editor , easy to build, just run `qmake` and `make`, my question is what is the cause of this seg fault?

Comment: memory allocation failed in main at 0x000055555555b6ae so use addr2line

Comment: The cause of the seg fault is a bug somewhere in this program. The bug can be anywhere. Unfortunately these kinds of bugs don't have a button somewhere that only needs to be pushed in order for an arrow to pop out and say: "here's the bug!". You will need to use a debugger, some analysis, and time, to be able to reliably reproduce the bug, then track it down and fix it.

Comment: please show your main.cpp where you instantiate your QApplication object.

Comment: https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/big-file-editor/blob/master/main.cpp

Comment: This is wrong: `BFEApplication(int argc, char *argv[]) : QApplication(argc, argv) { }` - you have to pass an reference to argc - otherwise QApplication internals will work on a dangling reference as described in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#QCoreApplication) in a big red box.

Comment: @chehrlic then why it is working ? because time to time application starting without the problem

Comment: Because a the dangling reference is not used until then or it points to a value which does not crash the application or something else. Just because there is a dangling pointer/reference somewhere doesn't mean your app crashes immediately - it just crashes when you try to access it and the content is garbage.